# Setting Back Ground image in LotusScript mail

Tags: lotusscript

I need to sent a mail with a background image attached to it . Can anyone help me out in this.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

1. If you need to do this manually then here what you need [Adding
   background colors or background images to emails and other Notes
   documents](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/Adding_background_colors_or_images_to_Notes_documents)
2. however if u need to do this via LotusScript you can try to add
   image to memo's field $BackgroundBody, this is the place where memo
   stores background image.
3. Also think about HTML way (when u construct body with html and set
   background image using HTML)

Comment: Thanks dmytro.I tried to build the mail body as html content,the code which i used to get the background image is as follows,Call stream.WriteText ({<html> <body style="background-image:url('http://servername/databasename/WhiteRose.jpg')" >  Dear } +doc.Getitemvalue("Fname")(0) +"<br> <br>  </br> </br> "+ configImageDoc.Getitemvalue("fldmessage")(0) + "<br> </br> "+ "Best Wishes " + "<br> </br>" + "ramya" +{<br></br></body> </html>}).... then also the background image is not getting attached to the mail body. what might be the reason for that??/